# Building a module based on ACIS kernel

Tags: amf, sat

I want to build a module/application that converts .SAT format to a 3D printing file format like .3mf and I want it to be built on ACIS kernel so that I can use pre-defined functions and...

I have access to ACIS kernel source code but I don't know where to start exactly. I know they have this framework called RADF but I'm not sure if it would help me for what I want.

The questions that I have are so basic but I really appreciate it if you answer them.

1. What does it mean to build an application based on a kernel exactly? Lets say I'm using VS, C# programming language and I have ACIS kernel source code. Do I have to start a new a project in VS and add ACIS libraries to it so that I can use its functions? I really need a good and informative answer for this so thank you in advance!
2. What does RADF do in this situation? Do I rally need it? Is it necessary if I want to use C#?(because ACIS is written in C++)
3. if the answer to the previous question is yes, I really need some help building the RADF and SPADotnet solutions. I can ask questions if someone has experience with it.
4. As I said I want the output of my application to be a .3mf file, does that mean that I have to use .3mf source code that is developed by the consortium? (the one that is on GitHub)

At last I want to say that I'm really trying to learn those things by reading the documentation and other stuff online, but I just don't find my answers

Answer (score 1):

Mohammad,
ACIS is a commercial toolkit that you must purchase a license in order to use it legally. I suggest you contact Spatial Corp to acquire a license. They are more than happy to support your workflow and answer the questions you ask.

1. ACIS is a C++ library. To expose the functionality you're after, you must write a wrapper that is appropriate for the language you want to use.
2. RADF is two things- a C# wrapper for the C++ library, as well as a basic application framework for creating a GUI application.
3. Contact Spatial for help on this.
4. Your best bet is to use the 3mf library from the consortium, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As Brad says, Spatial provides support to developers: https://spatial.custhelp.com/app/utils/login_form/.

I worked with ACIS some years ago, and I'd say, it's not a library you should use in a new project, unless your project uses very little of its functions, so you could easily migrate to another kernel later, or your project so heavily depends on compatibility with ACIS that you have no other choice.

I believe open-source libraries are our future, see if you can pick some of them.